# Dart Element.append() enters infinite loop

Tags: dart, infinite-loop

I have a whole bunch of Dart code that worked fine previously, so there are no bugs in my code. now however, with the latest Dart SDK (0.7.3.1_r27487) the following line makes my code enter an infinite loop:

document.body.append(SomeElement);

when I comment out this line no loop is entered, however the component I created does not display (is not attached to the DOM).

anyone have any ideas? I see on the web that people are mentioning other library functions entering infinite loops in particular circumstances. no mention of append() however.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. 
thanks

ps: bellow is the code in main() thats surrounding the crashing line. the definitions of various arguments passed into init() are omitted. the document.body.append() line is whats causing the infinite loop

```
void main() {
Function log_fun = (p_g,p_m) => print('$p_g:$p_m');
log_fun('FUN_ENTER','test.main()');

List<Map> posts_infos_by_pages_lst = test_data.get_test_data(log_fun);
visGroup_paged_scroll.init(draw_element_fun,
                           get_elements_pages_info_fun,

                           //called whenever visGroup_scroll loads new pages
                           //p_onNewPagesLoad_fun
                           () {},

                           //p_onComplete_fun
                           (DivElement                p_visGroup_scroll_element,
                            visGroup_paged.PagesCache p_pages_cache,
                            int                       p_total_pages_num,
                            int                       p_visGroup_scroll_height_int,
                            Function                  p_visGroup_pages_display_fun) {
                                document.body.append(p_visGroup_scroll_element);                                    
                           },
                           log_fun,
                           p_scroll_container_height_px : 600,
                           p_scroll_container_width_px  : 1000,                  
                           p_scroll_bar_width_px        : 80);
```

Comment: where does this happen? main()? some listener?

Comment: well good question. its happening inside of an onComplete callback, which itself is defined inside of main()... before that onComplete is called there is quite a bit of processing happening, so Im assuming something is done there that shouldnt be. all this stuff worked before however, and all that processing does not throw any exceptions (when I comment out the append() to prevent the infinite loop).

Comment: maybe some more context would help. could you post the relevant parts of your main() function?

Comment: added. Thanks for helping MarioP. please let me know if you need more detail

Comment: well, that looks more complex than I hoped. Does the endless loop really occur in append(), or is it called over and over and over again?

Comment: well that whole code without modification worked fine with the previous SDK release. so its def not in my code... when I commet out append() I see all log messages running fine and execution stops in p_onComplete_fun(), as it should. with append() uncommented the loop is entered... I do see the component being appended over and over again though, visually... and it quickly scrolls my browser window (meaning it attaches it over and over again freezing my console and visually extending the height of the page into infinity

Comment: well, append() basically translates to document.body.appendChild() in JavaScript, so normally that can't be it. Did you add a log before append()? Do you get the log entry one time or multiple times?